# Django-Filter: Search within an ArrayField with an Array?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have an `all_positions` datapoint that uses an arrayField. So some example data looks like:

```
all_positions: ["C", "1B"],
all_positions: ["RP", "CP"],
all_positions: ["CP"],
```

I'd like to be able to make a request similar to `/api/player-profiles/?all_positions=RP,CP` and return the second and third examples. Essentially, I want to return all players that have ANY of the positions passed into the URL in their `all_positions` data.

I've read about overlap, but not sure how I would integrate that into my django-rest filters. Here is what the filter currently looks like:

```
class PlayerProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    all_positions = CharInFilter(field_name='all_positions', lookup_expr='contains')
```

Comment: Have you changed `lookup_expr='contains'` to `lookup_expr='overlap'`

Comment: @Ahtisham that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the lookup filter in `lookup_expr` from `contains` to `overlap`:

```
class PlayerProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
       all_positions = CharInFilter(field_name='all_positions', lookup_expr='overlap')
```